# Creating Dataset and assigning variable names in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, naming-conventions

I have a r code that I am trying to translate in Matlab. I have a bunch of vectors that I column bind into a matrix and then assign specific names to those columns. How can I do the same in matlab?

So my R code is the following -

```
param = cbind(a1,b1,r1,ratio,s1,d1,ratio1)
colnames(param) = c("alpha","beta^2","rho","rho/beta^2","sigma^2","delta","delta/sigma^2")
```

For the first part, in matlab I have

```
param = [a1;b1;r1;ratio;s1;d1;ratio1]';
```

I do not know how to accomplish the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
colnames = {'alpha', 'beta^2', 'rho', 'rho/beta^2', 'sigma^2', 'delta', 'delta/sigma^2'}
```

Comment: Yes, how to assign these column names to param?